# Corona SDK, Lua

Tags: image, lua, coronasdk

HELLLPPPPP!!!!! I am programming in Corona SDK, and I am trying to insert a backround image, with the following code ---local backround = display.newImage("bluebackround.jpg")--- But it does not want to show up in the simulator. It keeps giving me the following message in the output, ---Failed to find image 'bluebackround.jpg'---. My image is saved in the project folder. I am using Microsoft Windows software. I have done another project using Corona, and I inserted images completely fine. Anyone know what's going on with my code and how to fix it? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You're new in here, so I advice you to read http://stackoverflow.com/tour at first. Then you'll notice mistakes you've made: wrong title (which should roughly explain what is your question about), starting with yelling and begging (it's obvious you are asking for help).

Answer (score 1):

```
 _W = display.contentWidth;
 _H = display.contentHeight;

  local image = display.newImageRect(--[["Name", width, heigth]] "bluebackround.jpg",_W, _H)
  image.x = _W/2; 
  image.y = _H/2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The your image need to be in the same folder as main.lua in your case. On the same level. Moreover, I think you misspell name of your image. You write 'bluebackround' without letter g in middle. So check name of the file.

From Corona [documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newImage.html)

> Image guildelines:
>
> - Corona supports PNG and JPG format,
> - Images should not contain an embedded ICC profile,
> - Avoid progressive JPG files since they will take much longer to load.